# Adjusting coordinates of a raster

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

I am working with air pollution data and I am unable to figure out how to adjust the coordinates of the raster file I am working with. The raw data I am working with is in the form of NETcdf4 at a resolution of .01*.01 available [here](https://wustl.app.box.com/v/ACAG-V4NA03-PM25/folder/119797060328?page=3)
This is how it looks like:

```
a <- raster("V4NA03_PM25_NA_201701_201701-RH35.nc")
a <- as.data.frame(a, xy=T)
```

[Raster info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BEwq.png)

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxbYj.png)

I use this file to crop out USA, but I require the latitudes and longitudes at .5*.5 resolution, in the form of, for instance, x = -170.5 y = -65.5, x = -170, y = -65, x = -169.5 y = -64.5 etc.

I use the following command:

```
a <- aggregate(a, fact = 50)
a <- as.data.frame(a, xy = T)
```

But then I get the following lat longs: -167.75, -167.25, 67.95, with number of rows down to 16296.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh8vz.png)

Am I doing something wrong? Or is my approach entirely wrong? Would rotation or reprojection help my cause?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As you read at the top of `[r]` questions, it is distinctly preferred not to put images in lieu of say, actual raster summaries (as in this case). As you've managed to get some of this into R object, a short cut on entering multi-line entries while you're editing your post/question is to go down a line (enter) then put `````, that is three back tics, at end of your multi-line, three back tics below it, and you resume entering problem description. That will help us help you. Why are you making your `raster` objects data.frame?

Comment: Well, that doesn't look like three back tics ```.